# How do I proceed on this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if there's a way to display more than one column on an aggregate result but without it affecting the group by.

I need to display the name alongside an aggregate result, but I have no idea what I am missing here.

This is the data I'm working with:

[image]

It is the result of the following query:

```
select * from Salesman, Sale,Buyer 
where Salesman.ID = Buyer.Salesman_ID and Buyer.ID = sale.Buyer_ID
```

I need to find the salesman that sold the most stuff (total price) for a specific year.

This is what I have so far:

```
select DATEPART(year,sale.sale_date)'year', Salesman.First_Name,sum(sale.price)
from Salesman, Sale,Buyer
where Salesman.ID = Buyer.Salesman_ID and Buyer.ID = sale.Buyer_ID
group by  DATEPART(year,sale.sale_date),Salesman.First_Name
```

This returns me the total sales made by each salesman.

[image]

How do I continue from here to get the top salesman of each year?

Maybe the query I am doing is completely wrong and there is a better way?

Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your desired output format?  Do you want your query to just return one row?  Do you want one row per year? etc

Comment: I need one row per year(in this case I will only have two rows) and each row will state the name and the total in sales of the salesman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select *
from(
    select DATEPART(year,s.sale_date) as SalesYear  -- Avoid reserved words for object names
            ,sm.First_Name
            ,sum(s.price) as TotalSales
            ,row_number() over (partition by DATEPART(year,s.sale_date)  -- Rank the data within the same year as this data row.
                                order by sum(s.price) desc   -- Order by the sum total of sales price, with the largest first (Descending).  This means that rank 1 is the highest amount.
                                ) as SalesRank    -- Orders your salesmen by the total sales within each year, with 1 as the best.
    from Buyer b
        inner join Sale s
            on(b.ID = s.Buyer_ID)
        inner join Salesman sm
            on(sm.ID = b.Salesman_ID)
    group by  DATEPART(year,s.sale_date)
                ,sm.First_Name
    ) a
where SalesRank = 1    -- This means you only get the top salesman for each year.
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! Any chance you can explain how? ^^

Comment: The explanation is in the comments in the code.  This is the same query you had, I have just replaced the `from <table1>, <table2>, <table3>` notation with proper `inner joins`.  The only actual difference is the addition of the `SalesRank` field which uses a `windowed function` to calculate a `row_number` of the total sales within each year.  The `select` around this then only returns those with a `SalesRank` of 1 - or - the best salesman.

Answer (score 1):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The answer to your question is to use window functions.  If there is a tie and you wand all values, then `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`.  If you always want exactly one -- even if there are ties -- then `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
select ss.*
from (select year(s.sale_date) as yyyy, sm.First_Name, sum(s.price) as total_price,
             row_number() over (partition by year(s.sale_date)
                                order by sum(s.price) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from Salesman sm join
           Sale s
           on sm.ID = s.Salesman_ID 
      group by year(s.sale_date), sm.First_Name
     ) ss
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that the `Buyers` table is unnecessary for this query.